# Use a React Component as a custom OverlayView in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps JavaScript API V3 to generate a map, with clustered map markers and draggable map markers. We decided against using some of the react libraries that make use of the google maps API. The reason being is that one, the drag would not allow to drag the whole marker and just a section of it and others didn't offer all the flexibility we require down the line.

I have a google map component (`GoogleMap.js`) that initialises the google map with options that are passed as props in the component, it also loops over a `mapMarker` array prop that contains an object of

1. `position` - latitude and longitude values
2. `icon` - a React component to use as the marker

It also creates a `MarkerClusterer` class using `@googlemaps/markerclustererplus`

#### GoogleMap.js

```
const GoogleMap = ({
  center,
  zoom,
  zoomControl,
  zoomControlPosition,
  fullscreenControl,
  scrollwheel,
  streetViewControl,
  mapTypeControl,
  scaleControl,
  mapTypeId,
  options,
  height,
  width,
  mapMarkers,
  onChildMouseUp
}) => {
  const [gmap, setGmap] = useState();
  const { google } = window;
  const { maps } = google || {};

  const initMap = async () => {
    const map = await new maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: { lat: center[0], lng: center[1] },
      zoom,
      zoomControl,
      zoomControlOptions: {
        position: maps.ControlPosition[zoomControlPosition]
      },
      fullscreenControl,
      scrollwheel,
      streetViewControl,
      scrollWheelZoom: "center",
      mapTypeControl,
      scaleControl,
      mapTypeId,
      ...options
    });

    if (mapMarkers && mapMarkers.length > 0) {
      const newBoundary = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

      const markers = mapMarkers.map((m) => {
        const { position, icon, draggable } = m;
        const marker = new CustomMarker(
          position,
          draggable,
          icon,
          map,
          onChildMouseUp
        );
        newBoundary.extend(marker.latlng);
        return marker;
      });

      if (mapMarkers.length > 1) map.fitBounds(newBoundary);

      // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
      new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
        calculator: (gMarkers, numStyles) => {
          let index = 0;
          const count = gMarkers.length;
          let dv = count;
          while (dv !== 0) {
            dv = parseInt(dv / 10, 10);
            index += 1;
          }

          index = Math.min(index, numStyles);
          return {
            text: `${count}`,
            index
          };
        },
        gridSize: 50,
        styles: [
          {
            className: "clusterMarker",
            width: 50,
            height: 18
          }
        ]
      });
    }

    return map;
  };

  const recenterMap = () => {
    const cntr = new google.maps.LatLng(center[0], center[1]);
    gmap.setCenter(cntr);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;

    const getMap = async () => {
      if (isMounted) {
        const data = await initMap();
        if (data) return data;
        return null;
      }
      return null;
    };

    getMap().then((m) => isMounted && setGmap(m));

    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // recenter map after center value updates
    if (gmap && center && center.length === 2) recenterMap();
  }, [center]);

  return <Map id="map" mapHeight={height} mapWidth={width} />;
};
```

`GoogleMap.js` uses a class `CustomMarker` that comes from `CustomMarker.js`. This class draws the marker onto the map at the correct position.

#### CustomMarker.js

```
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";

const { google } = window;

function CustomMarker(latlng, draggable, icon, map, onChildMouseUp) {
  // create global state to be accessed in prototype functions
  this.latlng = latlng;
  this.getDraggable = () => draggable;
  this.icon = icon;
  this.onChildMouseUp = onChildMouseUp;
  // create div that houses our custom marker
  this.div = document.createElement("div");
  // Once the LatLng and text are set, add the marker to the map.  This will
  // trigger a call to panes_changed which should in turn call draw.
  this.setMap(map);
}

// create prototype to display custom DOM element on map and access to custom methods
CustomMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

// init custom marker
CustomMarker.prototype.init = function init() {
  const container = this.div;

  container.style.position = "absolute";
  container.draggable = true;

  if (this.icon) {
    // use ReactDOMServer to render icon component as a string to be added as innerHTML
    const marker = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(this.icon);
    container.innerHTML = marker;
  }

  this.set("container", container);
  this.getPanes().floatPane.appendChild(container);
};

// draw function is function that is called initially to draw marker onto map
CustomMarker.prototype.draw = function draw() {
  if (!this.div) {
    // create div that houses our custom marker
    this.div = document.createElement("div");
  }
  // only draw marker if it has not been assigned the customMarker class
  if (!this.div.classList.contains("customMarker")) {
    this.div.classList.add("customMarker");

    const panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayImage.appendChild(this.div);

    // initialise
    this.init();
  }

  // call setPosition function
  this.setPosition();
};

CustomMarker.prototype.remove = function remove() {
  // Check if the overlay was on the map and needs to be removed.
  if (this.div) {
    this.div.parentNode.removeChild(this.div);
    this.div = null;
  }
};

CustomMarker.prototype.getPosition = function getPosition() {
  // return global latlng value
  return this.latlng;
};

CustomMarker.prototype.setPosition = function setPosition(pos) {
  // update global latlng value with current position of marker
  if (pos) this.latlng = pos;

  const projection = this.getProjection();
  if (!projection) return;

  // convert latlng value to pixel equivalent
  const point = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng);

  // set left and top values from values from point variable to place marker correctly on map
  if (point && point.x && point.y) {
    this.div.style.left = `${point.x}px`;
    this.div.style.top = `${point.y}px`;
  }
};

export default CustomMarker;
```

I am using `react-dom/server` `renderToString` function to convert the component to a HTML string to add it as the marker. However the problem I currently have is that in the component passed as in the `mapMarkers` prop as the `icon` property into `GoogleMap.js`

1. Any interactivity does not work, i.e `onClick` event listener
2. Context & global state does not work

#### MapMarker

```
const MapMarker = () => {
  // const store = useStoreState((store) => store);

  return (
    <Container onClick={() => alert("do action")}>
      £{Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

`useStoreState` uses `easy-peasy` a global state management that has a store with the `center` value of the google map. However when you remove the commented out code `const store = useStoreState((store) => store);` it's unable to get the store at all, as it is no longer in context. Obviously, rendering the component outside of the map, the store works as it is in context.

I have tried using something like `react-to-webcomponent` to convert the component to a web component and define a `customElements` for the component but again context and global state does not work in the marker component.

Is there any way around this?

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-leftpad-ezr9x?file=/src/CustomMarker.js) with the issue

Here is another [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-brook-eivu1?file=/src/MapMarker.js) using `react-to-webcomponent`

Answer (score 0):

I was on the same boat. I used renderToString I got the same results as you, but when I used ReactDOM.render, all my click handlers (and actual state of the component) started to work.
So, in your code the change should be something like this
From

```
const marker = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(this.icon);
container.innerHTML = marker;
```

To

```
ReactDOM.render(yourReactComponent, container)
```

Comment: Forgot I had done this initially, and still the same result as converting to a web component. My global store does not seem to be in context still. See here if you uncomment the commented out code in `MapMarker.js` https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-field-y5mbd?file=/src/MapMarker.js:802-854

Comment: I didn't get access to the store either, but I ended up creating a handler that a parent component can pass to the component which does have access to the state. I had to dispatch an action and regarding the data I need to render it, I just pass it as prop to avoid querying the global state. Not the best, but it did the trick for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that's going to work in my case. In my actual map marker component, it's a lot more detailed with various other reusable components in an external library using theming from styled components and many other contexts', that I can't pass down as props.