# How to use Google Map MarkerClusterer on OverlayView which is rendered via ReactDOM createPortal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been banging my head against the wall with google maps. See my initial issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68004895/use-a-react-component-as-a-custom-overlayview-in-google-maps/68011690)

I fixed the issue of using a react component as a map marker, by creating a portal with the OverlayView into a div. But now I'm faced with a bump in a rug now where I am now unsure how to create clustered markers?

Previously I used `@googlemaps/markerclustererplus` to create a cluster from an array of of markers created from a class `CustomMarker` that generates an `OverlayView` with the code snippet below.

```
const markers = mapMarkers.map((m) => {
  const { position, icon, draggable } = m;
  const marker = new CustomMarker(
    position,
    draggable,
    icon,
    map,
    onChildMouseUp
  );
  return marker;
});

// Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
  calculator: (gMarkers, numStyles) => {
    let index = 0;
    const count = gMarkers.length;
    let dv = count;
    while (dv !== 0) {
      dv = parseInt(dv / 10, 10);
      index += 1;
    }
    index = Math.min(index, numStyles);
    return {
      text: `${count}`,
      index
    };
  },
  gridSize: 50,
  styles: [
    {
      className: "clusterMarker",
      width: 50,
      height: 18
    }
  ]
});
```

Now I'm confused how to populate the 2nd argument in `MarkerClusterer` with the markers now I add markers in the components return statement

```
<Map id="map" mapHeight={height} mapWidth={width}>
  {gmap && mapMarkers?.length > 0 ? (
    <>
      {mapMarkers.map((m, i) => {
        return (
          <CustomMarkerNew key={i} position={m.position} googleMap={gmap}>
            {m.icon}
          </CustomMarkerNew>
        );
      })}
    </>
  ) : null}
</Map>
```

This is how the `CustomMarkerNew` component looks

#### CustomMarkerNew.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const OverlayView = (props) => {
  const { google } = window;
  const { googleMap, position, children } = props;

  const [latlng, setLatlng] = useState(position);
  const [container, setContainer] = useState(document.createElement("div"));
  const [overlay, setOverlay] = useState(undefined);

  const initOverlay = useCallback(() => {
    const overlayView = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    overlayView.setMap(googleMap);
    overlayView.getDraggable = () => true;
    setOverlay(overlayView);
    setLatlng(position);
    google.maps.OverlayView.preventMapHitsFrom(container);
  }, [googleMap, container]);

  const onAdd = useCallback(() => {
    // only draw marker if it has not been assigned the customMarker class
    if (!container.classList.contains("customMarker")) {
      container.classList.add("customMarker");
      container.style.position = "absolute";
      const panes = overlay.getPanes();
      panes.overlayImage.appendChild(container);
    }

    overlay.setPosition();
  }, [overlay]);

  const draw = useCallback(() => {
    container.style.position = "absolute";
    container.draggable = true;

    overlay.getPanes().floatPane.appendChild(container);

    overlay.setPosition();
  }, [overlay, container, latlng]);

  const onRemove = useCallback(() => {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container);
    setContainer(undefined);
    overlay.setMap(null);
  }, [container, overlay]);

  const setPosition = (pos) => {
    // update global latlng value with current position of marker
    if (pos) setLatlng(pos);

    const projection = overlay.getProjection();
    if (!projection) return;

    // convert latlng value to pixel equivalent
    const point = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(latlng);

    // set left and top values from values from point variable to place marker correctly on map
    if (point && point.x && point.y) {
      container.style.left = `${point.x}px`;
      container.style.top = `${point.y}px`;
    }
  };

  const bindFunctions = useCallback(() => {
    overlay.onAdd = onAdd.bind(this);
    overlay.draw = draw.bind(this);
    overlay.onRemove = onRemove.bind(this);
    overlay.setPosition = setPosition.bind(this);
    overlay.getDraggable = () => true;
  }, [overlay]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (overlay) {
      bindFunctions();
    }
  }, [overlay]);

  useEffect(() => {
    initOverlay();
  }, []);

  return (
    (overlay &&
      children &&
      container &&
      ReactDOM.createPortal(children, container)) ||
    null
  );
};

export default React.memo(OverlayView);
```

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-fog-2jvf2?file=/src/CustomMarkerNew.js) as an example

Any help would be much appreciated.